# Change fixity of function type (->)?

Tags: haskell, types, operator-precedence, type-level-computation

Doing some type-level computation I've come to a point where I want to change the fixity of `->` because it can't be mixed with left associative type operators of fixity 0. I know it doesn't work outright with the `TypeOperators` extension and `infixr 1 ->`, because it only returns the error `parse error on input ‘->’`.

Is there any extension or other means to modify the fixity of the function type operator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make a synonym:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

infixr 1 ~>
type (~>) = (->)
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution I think. It doesn't introduce confusion to those who expect `infixr 0 ->`.

Comment: `type (~>) = (->)` is somewhat better, because it can still be partially applied.